# RSA Private key renewal - How often?

Tags: security, encryption

Let's say I am using a RSA keypair to encrypt and decrypt a large amount of traffic over a public network. Assume all traffic is padded and the key is 2048 bits, how often would you recommend renewing the private key?

Is there a mathematical solution to how much encrypted data is needed in bytes that would allow a hacker to calculate the private key?

A real life example of this might be a messaging service which encrypts all traffic with one key.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14303492/102937), which states *"In 2009 the 768 bit number rsa-768 was cracked using about 1000 cores and 2 years of calculations. Assuming they used the General number field sieve (a very fair assumption) it would take them 7481 years to crack a 1024 bit number using the same hardware."*

Comment: @RobertHarvey: So... renew every 7000 years, just to be safe? ;)

Comment: Something like that.  2048 bits is probably closer to "heat death of the universe."

Comment: @RobertHarvey assuming that particular configuration. If you increase the computational power involved you can reduce the time to break the key. Other aspects have to be considered like a leak of your keystore.

Comment: @linuxutil: How many cores did you have in mind?

Comment: @RobertHarvey on march last year the IEEE did an experiment with quantum computers and 5 qubits came close to break an rsa key. - https://goo.gl/lNWxgl

Comment: DigiCert claim that would take 1.5 million years to break their 2048 bits RSA keys - https://goo.gl/HLxMnG

Comment: I think this should be migrated to Information Security.

Comment: How about once per connection or once per minute?